# Tomcat Start up problems

Tags: java, tomcat7

I do not have tomcat start up file in my tomcat folder. I can see only these four files

1. tomcat7w .application
2. tomcat7.application
3. tomcat. julli(jar)
4. bootstrap(jar)

I usually start tomcat by opening the `tomcat.exe` file. For a change, I opened `tomcat7w` last time. After that i am not able to open tomcat it shutdown automatically.

How can fix it back without uninstalling tomcat? (I am talking about windows I do not know it matters but to clarify things )

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7w is a monitoring file for the Tomcat web service which shouldn't have effected or started a server nor modified your Tomcat files. There are two ways you could proceed you could try the generic restart your computer which if somehow your server did get started and this is preventing you from opening another instance. The other option is to open up your taskmanager and attempt to manually close the server instance or anything else that may be preventing you from starting it.

Comment: IN taskManager I can see the Tomcat but it is not running in my desktop. Usually after i Started tomcat7 through cmd then it halt I could not use same cmd window for other purposes. but now after startup i can even type in the same cmd window. WHY is that?

Comment: I am by no means a Tomcat wizard I typically do all of my Tomcat testing via Eclipse. But I would imagine something in your Tomcat file is corrupted because it should be running as a '.bat' I believe which would run in a command prompt window and once your server halts that should exit the script closing the window. So there's most likely another more complex issue. Perhaps someone else that stumbles upon this can offer more insight.